# set option label of selected value in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, select, default-value

Using React I want to set a defaulvalue for my select and diplay the label in the options.
This is what I've built so far :

```
<Select showSearch style = {{ width: '100%' }}
                   placeholder = "Selection la choix de votre numÃ©ro de tÃ©lÃ©phone "
                   optionFilterProp = "children"
                   onChange = {handleChangeSelect}

                   defaultValue = {extraitMP3[ids].Mp3[idJson].visibilite}
                   onFocus = {handleFocusSelect}
                   onBlur = {handleBlurSelect}
                   filterOption = {(input, Option) => Option.props.children.toLowerCase().indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) >= 0}>

    <Option value = "1"> Visible dans la recherche et sur ma fiche </Option>
    <Option value = "2"> Visible sur ma fiche uniquement </Option>
    <Option value = "3"> Masqué </Option>
</Select>
```

The result now is showing {extraitMP3[ids].Mp3[idJson].visibilite} which is equal to one of the option values but what I want to display is the option labels. Any help to change what to display from values to their labels in the defaulValue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the options in a Map, and then look up the text for the option:

Somewhere in your component's module but not in the component itself (no need to recreate it all the time):

```
const selectOptions = new Map([
    ["1", "Visible dans la recherche et sur ma fiche"],
    ["2", "Visible sur ma fiche uniquement"],
    ["3", "Masqué"],
]);
```

Then when rendering, look it up:

```
defaultValue={selectOptions.get(extraitMP3[ids].Mp3[idJson].visibilite)}
```

also, use the map for rendering the options. So the rendering code would look something like:

```
<Select
            showSearch
            style={{ width: '100%' }}
            placeholder="Selection la choix de votre numÃ©ro de tÃ©lÃ©phone "
            optionFilterProp="children"
            onChange={handleChangeSelect}

            defaultValue={selectOptions.get(extraitMP3[ids].Mp3[idJson].visibilite)}
            onFocus={handleFocusSelect}
            onBlur={handleBlurSelect}
            filterOption={(input, Option) => Option.props.children.toLowerCase().indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) >= 0}
          >
          {[...selectOptions].map(([value, label]) => <Option value="{value}"> {label} </Option>)}
</Select>
```

Comment: I did exactly what you told and I am getting : `TypeError: selectOptions.entries(...).map is not a function`

Comment: @Ahmed - My bad, I forgot to spread them. And if spread, no need for `entries`. See the updated answer (all that's different is the bit where we output the options).

Comment: now it's working but it is not setting the defaultvalue so I did a :                               `{console.log('Select Options',selectOptions.get(extraitMP3[ids].Mp3[idJson].visibilite))}` and it is undefined and the {console.log('Select Options',extraitMP3[ids].Mp3[idJson].visibilite)} is giving me the results

Comment: @Ahmed - That tells us that that `extraitMP3[ids].Mp3[idJson].visibilite` is not an `===` match for the values. (Map's `get` requires an `===` match for the key.) Perhaps it's a number rather than a string; if so, change the map to use numbers for the keys rather than strings. You're the only one who can check that.